# ElasticSearch: How to Match all fields in Mapping Type

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

**Question**
I am trying to write an ElasticSearch query that matches all properties of a mapping type (MyFirstMappingType). If one property does not match it should not return that item. They should not mix match to get match.

**Mapping**

```
  "mappings": {
    "item": { 
      "_all":       { "enabled": "false"  },
      "properties": { 
        "MyFirstMappingType": {
          "properties": {
            "field1":  { "type": "keyword" },
            "field2":  { "type": "keyword" }, 
            "field3":  { "type": "text", "index": "false" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This query returns items when an item matches each of those fields. But when an item has more than one "MyFirstMappingType" it will mix and match. For example this query will still return this item.

```
GET myfirst/item/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 38,
  "_source": [
    "MyFirstMappingType"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": "foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field2": "bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field3": "world"
          }
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

```
          "MyFirstMappingType" : [
            {
              "field1" : "foo",
              "field2" : "bar",
              "field3" : "hello"
            },
            {
              "field1" : "foo",
              "field2" : "world",
              "field3" : "foo"
            },
            {
              "field1" : "foo",
              "field2" : "foo",
              "field3" : "world"
            }
          ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query on each [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) object independently, you need to define `MyFirstMappingType` to be of [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

Adding a working example with index mapping and search query

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "MyFirstMappingType": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "MyFirstMappingType",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "MyFirstMappingType.field1": "foo"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "MyFirstMappingType.field2": "bar"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "MyFirstMappingType.field3": "world"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @OneThumbs please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to change the mapping of our index. If making it a "nested" type is the only solution, then I may be out of luck. But for the sake of finding the solution I will still try this out to determine if it returns the desired results. Thanks!

Comment: @OneThumbs AFAIK there is no other way apart from using nested type to achieve your required result. Please do let me know if this solution worked for you ;-)

Comment: @OneThumbs did you try with `nested` data type ?

Comment: Yes! This worked as described. Thank you for the help.